# Concatenated field from query populated in another field in a table

Tags: combobox, concatenation, ms-access-2013

I am new to Access and I am using Access 2013.  I have a table called Employees which has the employees `First_Name`, `Last_Name` and then a Combo Box that is going to have the `Full_Name`.  I have a query that pulls the `First_Name` and the `Last_Name` and Concatenates it to the `Full_Name` field.

Now when I go to my form and add a new employee and click save the field `Full_Name` in the employee table does not take the `Firs_Name` and `Last_Name` and put it into that field.  I am not sure what I am missing. I have to go to the `Full_Name` field after I put the new employee in and go to the drop down where the `Full_Name` is there.  I would like it to automatically put the `Full_Name` in there.

Comment: Do you mean that the Employees table has fields First_Name, Last_Name, AND Full_Name?  This would be very strange.

Comment: @Smandoli Yes, that is what it would have.  The Full_Name would be a drop down that would auto populate the users Full_Name.  This is for learning purposes.  I have a query that concatenates the First_Name and Last_Name fields. Then I have a combo box in the Employee table that would have the Full_Name. Would it be better to just have a Full_Name field?  Still would like to accomplish this because of the learning involved.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities that I see:

### A. The table is updated, but the form isn't refreshing.

Access forms often don't refresh data as instantly as you would like, and that could be the problem here.

1. If you add a record, close the form and re-open the form.  Does the combo box show correctly?
2. Try adding a record and clicking "Save".  Then press Shift-F9 on your keyboard.  Does that make the combo box show correctly?

If yes, then that's the problem.  You need to add a [requery or refresh method](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/refresh-or-requery-data-HA010256400.aspx) to the VBA code for your "Save" button.  (From what you've written, I'm presuming there is VBA code in there.)

### B. The table isn't being updated.

If the tests above didn't work, that suggests a field in the table hasn't been updated.  You are doing it manually, when you pick the Full_Name in the combo box.  In that case, you need to revise the code for the button.

**About First and Last Name:**

It is better to not have fields for full name, last name *and* first name -- that means you are storing the names twice, which will lead to problems in your situation.

The typical arrangement is to store first and last names.  You can obtain the full name by concatenating those two, which you can do either in a query or in the form.

Alternatively, you could store the full name in one field.  To obtain first and last names, you would separate them using functions -- again, in a query or form.  This is less common, because less flexible.  But it still avoids the problems that are created by storing the same data twice.

Which one is better?  That simply depends on your needs.